# jQuery On click, toggle next() element, but close any siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a functoin so that whent he user clicks on span.open, the next element with the class .footer-menu-accordion opens up. This toggle feature works fine. However if I click on the next span.open (for example, I've clicked on the span next to the Men anchor and then the span next to the Women anchor), then the .footer-menu-accordion that has already been opened does not close. It only closes if I click on the span.open again.

I would like it so that each time I click on a span.open, the .footer-menu-accordion immediately following it will open, but if there are any other .footer-menu-accordion divs open, those will close. I think I need to target siblings but I'm not sure how. Here is my html:

```
    <div class="dropdown-container">
          <a class="level-1 direct">Men</a><span class="open"></span> 
    </div>

    <div class="footer-menu-accordion">
       <a class="level-2"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown-container">
          <a class="level-1 direct">Women</a><span class="open"></span> 
    </div>

    <div class="footer-menu-accordion">
       <a class="level-2"></a>
    </div>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
function mobileMainNav(){
    $('a.level-1.direct').click(function(){
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    }); 


    $('span.open').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('arrow');
        $(this).parent().next('.footer-menu-accordion').slideToggle();
        if ($(this).siblings(':visible')) {
            $(this).siblings.hide();
        };
    }); 

};
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: you can try $('.footer-menu-accordion').slideUp() to close them all before calling .slideToggle()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then it should be possible to achieve what you need by updating your jQuery script like so:

```
function mobileMainNav(){
    $('a.level-1.direct').click(function(){
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    }); 


    $('span.open').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('arrow');

        // Toggle accordion menu related to this span
        $(this).parent().next('.footer-menu-accordion').slideToggle();

        // Hide other accordion menus that are not related to this span, 
        // via slideUp()
        $('span.open')
        .not(this)
        .parent()
        .next('.footer-menu-accordion')
        .slideUp(); 

        // Remove the arrow class on other menus
        $('span.open')
        .not(this)
        .removeClass('arrow');
    }); 

};
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes! This is working exactly how I want it. The only thing I need to do is also remove the "arrow" class to other accordion menus. I've tried to add toggleClass('arrow') to the bottom of your function but it didn't work. Any auggestions?

Comment: @KatherineMichelle great! Glad it's almost there :-) I've just updated the answer based on what I understand from your use of `toggleClass('arrow')` - does this help?

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks :)

Comment: @KatherineMichelle you're welcome - glad I could help :-)